# N nested iterations

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an array with N objects

```
var test = [obj1, objc2, ..., objN]
```

The object is in this format

```
{"Key", "number", "Name" : "string", "OtherFields" : "Data"}
```

I want to iterate like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < test.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 2; k < test.length; k++) {
      console.log(test[i].Name + test[j].Name + test[k].Name)
    }
  }
}
```

How can i achieve this result for n objects in the array ?

Example:

I have arrays `[1, 2, 3, 4] , [2,4,5], [1,2]`

i want to get this result:

```
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 4 1
1 4 2
1 5 1
1 5 2
.....
.....
4 5 2
```

Those arrays are not always 3 but can be any number >= 2

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide some sample input and output that illustrate exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to do that. What is the end goal?

Comment: I'm guessing that he wants to keep nesting for loops, with the starting indices increasing by 1 each time. But what I think he _really_ wants is to generate all permutations or combinations, which the nested for loops wouldn't achieve.

Comment: Please consider editing your question so that users know what you're talking about. It's easier for us to answer a question when we know what your goal is with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want permutations.

Here is a recursive approach:

```
function perm(test, max_depth, depth, s){
    if(depth === undefined)
        depth = max_depth;
    if(s === undefined)
        s = '';
    if(depth == 0)
        console.log(s);
    for(var i=depth; i<test.length;i++){
        perm(test, max_depth, depth-1, s + test[i].Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var N = 10;
var n = 3;

var test = [];
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    test.push({"Name" : "obj" + i});
}

function log_name_combinations(a, n) {
    function nestedlog(a, maxlvl, lvl, s) {
        if (lvl < maxlvl) {
            for (var i = lvl; i < a.length; i++) {
                nestedlog(a, maxlvl, lvl+1, s + a[i].Name);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(s);
        }
    }

    nestedlog(a, n, 0, "");
}

log_name_combinations(test, n);
```

[Demo at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jseegj6t/1/)

PS: Why are you starting the `i`th level iteration at the `i`th index?